# Compare the averages of my lists

Tags: code-golf, number, array

### Getting the average of a list  (e.g `[2,6,7]`)

- Get the length of the list: `[2,6,7] -> 3`
- Sum the numbers in the list: `2 + 6 + 7 = 15`.
- Divide the sum by their count: `15 / 3 = 5`.

You should compare the averages of two lists of *positive* integers **N** and **M**, by returning a value if **N** has a higher average, another value if **M** has a higher average, and another one in case of a tie.

---

## I/O rules

All the [standard Input and Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) are allowed.

#### Input

You may take input as two separate lists, a nested list, or anything else you consider suitable for the task. Please specify the format.

#### Output

The values provided have to be distinct and must consist of at least one non-whitespace character. Also, they *must* be consistent between runs (a single value for **N**, a single value for **M**, a single value for **Tie**). Please specify those in your answer. The values can be non-empty Strings, Bool values, Integers, or anything you consider suitable.

---

## Specs

- The lists will not necessarily have equal length.
- You are guaranteed that the lists are non-empty.

---

## Test Cases

I chose the values `N wins`, `M wins` and `Tie`, which are pretty much self-evident.

```
N, M                     ->   Output     (Averages)

[7], [6]                 -> N wins  (N has 7, M has 6 )
[4,5], [4,4]             -> N wins  (N has 4.5, M has 4)
[2,3,4], [4,5,6]         -> M wins  (N has 3, M has 5)
[4,1,3], [7,3,2,1,1,2]   -> Tie     (both have 2.666...)
[100,390,1], [89,82,89]  -> N wins  (N has 163.666..., M has 86.666...)
[92,892], [892,92]       -> Tie     (lists are basically identical) 
[10,182], [12,78,203,91] -> Tie     (both have 96)
```

---

[Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. Explanations are encouraged! This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13198#13198).

Comment: if my language of choice only supports integers, can I take input multiplied by 1000? That way the calculated averages would still be accurate to 3 decimal places

Comment: @Mayube Yes, that is allowed

Comment: We have to return an output of at least 1 character. Does that mean we are required to return a character or a string? Or do you mean an output whose string value is of a least 1 character?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The output given must be at least 1 character long (you cannot return an empty string, but can return any String of at least 1 character, and also any non-whitespace character). IT's up to you.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sorry, I must not have been explicit enough. Can I return other things than strings, if they have a string representation that is not the empty string? I think about numbers, for instance.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yes, you can return integers as well (most of the answers do so)

Comment: Could you clarify then that the output can be something else than a string in the question directly? Because to me, the question says "you must return a string, and that string may not be empty".

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I think it is pointless, but I will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 5 bytes

```
♂æi-s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///RzKbDyzJ1i///j442NDDQUTC2BBKGsToK0RaWOgoWRkBsGRsLAA)

`1` for `N > M`, `0` for `N = M`, `-1` for `N < M`.

Explanation:

```
♂æi-s Takes input in format [N, M]
♂æ    Map average
  i   Dump to stack in reverse
   -  Subtract
    s Get sign
```

Answer (score 15):

### Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
Order@@Mean/@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwEEX3nmKgUNrywWSiNUGEXKC0V5BWqYu60OxCzp4mIrh7894MzK933@m9xjh2z@UzLNY@hn4u7encFm5Y3Uod@YK8bwL8PQRkrlCnqUK1zwyVOJsax46ESq5JjRNL8F6kEFBGQKaqDTRDmz2ZzLx5hjkOIHW2ktFosFAwMoQitPHyWqbZkb3ReKXS0vZy/AM)

`Function` which expects a list of two lists. `Mean/@#` takes the arithmetic mean of each list in the input, then those means are passed into `Order`, which returns `-1` if the first list wins, `0` if there is a tie, and `1` if the second list wins.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

*(Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.)*

Here are two 50-byte solutions:

```
f=(N,M,a=eval(N.join`+`)/N.length)=>M?(a-f(M))/0:a

(N,M,A=a=>eval(a.join`+`)/a.length)=>(A(N)-A(M))/0
```

Returns **Infinity** for N, **-Infinity** for M, and **NaN** for a tie.

The first solution may require a bit of explanation due to the recursion:

On the first call to the function, `a` is initialized as the average of the `N` array:

```
a=eval(N.join`+`)/N.length
```

`M` has a value at this point, so the first part of the conditional expression is called:

`M ? (a-f(M))/0 : a 
     ----------`

The function is called within this expression, this time substituting `M` for `N`.

On this second call to the function, `a` is initialized as the average of `N` –– which was `M` in the previous call.

Since there is no second parameter during this call to the function, the second part of the conditional expression is triggered, which returns the average:

`M ? (a-f(M))/0 : a 
                 --`

We can now understand the expression better:

```
(a - f(M)) / 0
```

It's:

```
(the average of N  minus  the average of M) divided by 0
```

The difference between the averages will be a positive number, a negative number, or 0.

Dividing the difference by 0 results in **Infinity**, **-Infinity**, or **NaN** – providing the three distinct values as required.

**Test Cases:**

```js
f=(N,M,a=eval(N.join`+`)/N.length)=>M?(a-f(M))/0:a

console.log(f([7], [6]                 )) // N wins  (N has 7, M has 6 )
console.log(f([4,5], [4,4]             )) // N wins  (N has 4.5, M has 4)
console.log(f([2,3,4], [4,5,6]         )) // M wins  (N has 3, M has 5)
console.log(f([4,1,3], [7,3,2,1,1,2]   )) // Tie     (both have 2.666...)
console.log(f([100,390,1], [89,82,89]  )) // N wins  (N has 163.666..., M has 86.666...)
console.log(f([92,892], [892,92]       )) // Tie     (lists are basically identical) 
console.log(f([10,182], [12,78,203,91] )) // Tie     (both have 96)
```

Comment: Could you save a couple of bytes by moving `A` to the function parameters?

Comment: `N=>M=>((A=a=>eval(a.join`+`)/a.length)(N)-A(M))/0`

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
Sign[Mean@#-Mean@#2]&
```

1 for `#` wins, -1 for `#2` wins, 0 for tie.

Comment: or, equally long, `Sign[#-#2&@@Mean/@#]&`

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

Soooo many modifiers (`Y` and `Z`). I can't find a way to make it shorter. `sum / number_of_elements` is three bytes. It might be a better way to do `-ZS`, but I can't find one.

```
YmiYm-ZS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzI3MzJXNyr4//9oEx1DHeNYrmhzHWMdIyDbUMcoFgA)

```
           % Take first input implicitly
Ym         % Mean of that input
  i        % Grab second input
   Ym      % Mean of that input
     -     % Subtract
      ZS   % Sign
```

Returns `1` if the first input is larger, `0` if they tie, and `-1` if the second input is larger.

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```
(x,y)->cmp(mean(x),mean(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEEX3nsJlAl/ITBKTLPQipYsiFiptKVKhPX1M4kbS1TDvvZnXZxw6G/tbFBt2ebk/pkVMz24Wm0SZu5RxeQ/zOs6iF41rcW6urZSnP2hgMzYwlWDoxIqyOF4RdJYuVZwWAlcJKQUdFChnPsAzfKiakBn/AkY4vgD5oonhPFhpBEpR/AI)

Returns `1` if the first average is larger, `-1` if second is, and `0` if they tie.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

**1** if `M` wins, **-1** if `N` wins and **0** for a tie.

```
vyOyg/}.S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/rNK/Ml2/Vi/4///oaBMd01gdBSBlEhsLAA)

**Explanation**

```
v           # for each y in list of lists
 yO         # sum y
   yg       # get length of y
     /      # divide
      }     # end loop
       .S   # compare
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda p:cmp(*[sum(l)*1./len(l)for l in p])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoIwFET3nqJLSn60/xekJfEktQtUiCSlNAgxnr62sJqZ9yb81vfsKQ63e3Td9Hh1LLTPKRSl@WxT4XiJ54vrfWrDvDDHRs@C5fH7Hl3PsA3L6Fc2FKMP21pwHk1jgZmrPZkK6lwrqNIgkCn3WcNhEWQGTTKUBgIljEKA1AIwK6VBESiduM5JByTQxxVQ7QgJGgUkJGi0fw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(x,y)sign(mean(x)-mean(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYo7DoMwEET7nILSKw0WuzafFEi5B3KBECAKoAiK4PRmcaqZ92b24eh/Y5xaa238mBMXfZd5M@vYb@akPOVFFCfTeZQBmYYP9FIWOK3JlKhClqQHwz2y1lUUGPK/cwFu5JlYUDeQwuHNgeIN)

Takes two vectors `x.y` as input, takes the `mean` of both vectors, and subtract one from the other. Get the sign of this, to get `1`, `0` and `-1` for the three different alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 49 bytes

```python
lambda N,M:cmp(1.*sum(N)/len(N),1.*sum(M)/len(M))
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##LYpBDoIwEEXXcgqWhfxoZwBpSTwCXABZoEIggUoUYjw9Furqz3tvpu/cPQ2v7eW6DvV4e9R@gTy7j5OgY/heRlEEp6ExdvAXuRN5EKyfrh8anzLvML16M4tWhL2ZllkENpZpBb88V14ZI9nOGLEFRmR3xwSuEqJNpLawBQJbTVIi0hK0JaWhGEpbr7dlJxnavYLUroiRKrCMoKn6AQ)

Comment: "...[the three outputs] must be consistent between runs"

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

Prompts for a list of two lists. Prints `1` if the left has higher average, 0 if they have the same average, and `¯1` if the right has higher average.

```apl
×-/(+/÷≢)¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc0xCsJAEAXQ3lP8MouKO5NodmMlnkRQoxBJ0CB4ArXQTqxsrOxsBHtzk71I3BVExOBUw8ybP4MsaQ5XgySNS7NZ99NZ1lvGi7I4NltevVXczfYsHhezP7h1aXYnUJSMxnkXMsqnoy4eV4rm03iS1/Cqd0TNa4QCXqMj8FU/LEDbOja7WyD@QoYPS9wBPqkVeQTfstBytj2BRQUjKeFrCbJUaSiG0uKXaTfnl2G4pvop2SDlGDFCBZY@NIkn)

`⎕` prompt

`(`…`)¨` apply the following tacit function to each:

`+/` the sum

`÷` divided by

`≢` the tally

`-/` insert (and evaluate) a minus between them

`×` signum

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, <s>81</s> <s>66</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

*saved 15 bytes thanks to Luke*

*saved 2 bytes thanks to Justin Mariner*

```
n=>m=>Math.sign((a=b=>eval(b.join`+`)/b.length)(m)-a(n))
```

Tie is 0, M is 1 and N is -1. Called using currying syntax, eg. `f([7])([6])`

Comment: You can improve this by quite a few bytes: you can remove the variable assignment, you can use curry syntax, you can remove the alert, and you can easily sum arrays by using `eval(a.join\`+\`)`. `a=>(b=a.map(c=>eval(c.join\`+\`)/c.length))[0]-b[1]?b[0]>b[1]:0` for 61 bytes. It takes input as an array of arrays, and outputs `0` for a tie, `true` for  M and `false` for N.

Comment: why don't you post it as your own answer?

Comment: You could save two more bytes by inlining the function (`a`) the first time it's used: ``n=>m=>Math.sign((a=b=>eval(b.join`+`)/b.length)(m)-a(n))``.

Answer (score 3):

## **Pyth, <s>10</s> <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes**

Thanks @isaacg for saving a byte

```
._-F.O
```

Input is taken as a nested list, `[N, M]`. Outputs `-1` if `N < M`, `1` if `N > M` and `0` if they are equal.

[Try It Online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=._-F.O&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B7%5D%2C+%5B6%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B4%2C5%5D%2C+%5B4%2C4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C+%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B4%2C1%2C3%5D%2C+%5B7%2C3%2C2%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B100%2C390%2C1%5D%2C+%5B89%2C82%2C89%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B92%2C892%5D%2C+%5B892%2C92%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B10%2C182%5D%2C+%5B12%2C78%2C203%2C91%5D%5D&debug=0)

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing `h.+` with `-F`

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 68 bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v)$r[]=array_sum($v)/count($v);echo$r[0]<=>$r[1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKUS7@4aYqsQHW1ooGNoYRSroxBtaKRjbqFjZGCsY2kYG2v9Py2/KDUxOUMDrFQhsVilTFOlKDrWNrGoKLEyvrg0VwMoop@cX5pXAmJZpyZn5AMVGMTa2NoBaUOgEf8B)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
<?=($s=array_sum)($a=$_GET[0])/count($a)<=>$s($b=$_GET[1])/count($b);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKUS7@4aYqsQHW1ooGNoYRSroxBtaKRjbqFjZGCsY2kYG2vNZW8HVGuroVJsm1hUlFgZX1yaq6mhkmgL1hptEKupn5xfmlcCFNK0sbVTKdZQSYLKGSLkkjSt//8HAA)

[spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
-1 less then , 0 tie , 1 greater then

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>65</s> 43 Bytes

*Saved 22 bytes thanks to nimi!*

```
a x=sum x/sum[1|_<-x] 
x#y=compare(a x)$a y
```

<s>There has to be a much better way... But type conversions screwed me.</s>

**Usage**

```
(#) [7] [6]
```

Returns `GT` if the first argument wins, `LT` if the second argument wins, and `EQ` if they tie.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdHLasMwEAXQfb7iQrKwYeJasi1bUH9CsuouiKIkhoj6ESK3taH/7spu00eSUi2GWUiHe9FB26eiLIdBo8vtc4Xuzs0Ne3u8X3YKs27e57umOupT4bkr/kKjHyptauTYNzPgeDJ1iwW8uY9NqrARCpdnucQar6a2gLfGQVukhNW0CPiXSEyJGmes/kHiIDkz8ZXCKRqFUaMfkZyy@q1EZyO5kYRR5IzUWdztjLj6MB5MMXHetmkP7vVLAR4IIYIguFJYGFIkQ2JOyiRlnDKpbvVhIvo0zpEy8RcqR4VPIifJ1Xe9r2ilsa2F@zhstTU7XZY9zL6o23H3cR2TWDaKjFOaEQ8jki7y7bJS@MM7)

Comment: No need to cast `sum$x` with `f.`. Also: `length x` can be replaced with `sum[1|_<-x]`, so you can get rid off `f` completely: `a x=sum x/sum[1|_<-x]`.

Comment: Ah nice! Didn't even think to do that.

Comment: ... oh and in `#`: `...(a x)$a y`.

Comment: @nimi Should have taken your own answer! Thanks for the tips.

Comment: ... even better: go pointfree with your main function, then you can even save the name for it: `(.a).compare.a`.  Usage : `(  (.a).compare.a ) [7] [6]`.

Comment: One more: `[1|_<-x]` is the same as `(1<$x)`.

Answer (score 3):

### TI-Basic, <s>25</s> <s>21</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to lirtosiast

```
:tanh(ᴇ9mean(L₁-mean(L₂
```

Comment: This can be golfed by using `Ans` instead of `C`: `mean(L₁)>mean(L₂:Ans+3(mean(L₁)=mean(L₂`, 21 bytes.

Comment: You can remove the `(` and the `)`.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 10 bytes

```
*@-&(+/%#)
```

One list given on the left, one on the right.  Will return _1 if the left average is smaller, 1 if it's bigger, and 0 if they're equal

- `(+/%#)` is a standard J fork for calculating the average of a list
- `&` provides a variation on the dyadic fork.  it applies the right side (the average verb, in this case) to both arguments, and then passes them along to the verb on the left side, which in this case is...
- `*@-` subtract followed by "sign of": so the right avg is subtracted from the left, and we are given the sign of the result -- _1, 1, or 0

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
S÷Lµ€IṠ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of the two lists, `N,M` which returns:
`[-1]` for `N`;
`[1]` for `M`; and
`[0]` for a tie.
As a full program it prints the result (single item lists print their content only, so `-1`, `1`, or `0`).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/48HafQ1sfNa3xfLhzwf///6MNDXQMLYxidRSiDY10zC10jAyMdSwNYwE)**

#### How?

```
S÷Lµ€IṠ - Link: list of lists, [N,M]
   µ€   - perform the chain to the left for €ach (of N, M)
S       -   sum
  L     -   length
 ÷      -   divide (yields the average)
     I  - incremental differences (yields [avg(M) - avg(N)])
      Ṡ - sign (yields: [1] if avg(M)>avg(N); [-1] if avg(N)>avg(M); or [0] if equal)
```

Comment: I knew Jelly would be pretty good at this challenge, I just don't know the language very well. Well done on beating me :P

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is not possible in, say, 5...!

Comment: @JonathanAllan I am? Basically to get the averages you map the average function, which isn't a builtin yet, so you use the shortest (I suppose) counterpart, `S÷L`, and then you convert it to single-link via `S÷¥L$` which can be shortened to `S÷Lµ` since it's at the very start of the program and then you put an `€` right there to map and then since there's no builtin for comparing you'd use `_/Ṡ` but you can shorten to `IṠ` since that's still 3 distinct cmp outputs...yeah, pretty sure it can't be done in 5. Also 5 won't help since I FGITW'd. :)

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 91 <del>98</del> bytes

```
u,v,j;f(x,y,a,b)int*a,*b;{for(u=v=0;x--;u+=a[x])for(j=0;j<y;)v+=b[j++];j=u*y-v;x=j>0?2:!j;}
```

Wrong place for C and probably the only answer that doesn't need division. At least the code is displayed without a slider.

Return 0,1,2 for `M>N`, `M=N`, `M<N` respectively. Takes input as `length of M`, `length of N`, `M`, `N`.

Comment: Is taking length as an argument within the specs? Cuts significant code from a lot of these if it is.

Comment: I don't know if there's another way for C to retrieve the length of an array. The length itself is more like an intrinsic part of array.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 25 bytes

```
{sign [-] .map:{.sum/$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujgzPU8hWjdWQS83scCqWq@4NFdfJb629r@1QnFipUKahoaNoYKRgrGdjoINkFIwsdPU/A8A)

Takes a single argument, a two-element list of lists of numbers.  Returns `1` if the first list has a greater average, `-1` if the second list does, and `0` if the averages are equal.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>60</s> 54 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to @Luke and @Neil*

```js
(i,[x,y]=i.map(v=>eval(v.join`+`)/v.length))=>y-x&&x>y
```

Takes input as a 2-element array `[N, M]`. Outputs `true`, `0`, or `false` for `N`, `Tie`, or `M`, respectively.

### Explanation

```js
(i,                 // input array: [N, M]
    [x,y] =         // destructure assignment: set x and y to...
    i.map(v=>       // the input values mapped as...
        eval(v.join`+`) // the sum, by joining the array with +
        / v.length      // divided by the length
    )
) => y-x && x>y     // return 0 for tie, or the result of avg(N) > avg(M)
```

### Test Snippet

Input numbers separated by spaces/commas.

```js
f=
(i,[x,y]=i.map(v=>eval(v.join`+`)/v.length))=>y-x&&x>y
```

```html
<div oninput="O.value=f([N.value,M.value].map(x=>x.split(/[ ,]+/)))">N <input id=N> M <input id=M></div>
Out: <input id=O disabled>
```

Comment: You can probably save some bytes by replacing `Math.sign(y-x)` by `y-x?x>y:0`. Outputs `0` for `Tie`, `true` for `N` and `false` for `M`.

Comment: `x-y&&x>y` perhaps?

Comment: @Neil Nice, even better

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```
a=>(b=(c=a.map(d=>eval(d.join`+`)/d.length))[0])-c[1])?b>0:0
```

Outputs `0` for `Tie`, `true` for `N` and `false` for `M`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
{$CM$+*a/#*a}
```

This is a function that takes a list of lists. Returns `1` if the first average is bigger, `-1` if the second is bigger, `0` if tied. [Run all test cases here.](https://tio.run/##RYoxDsIwEAT7vGKluApC@M4Ovqup8wLLRUoalB7x9uMcS9DNzuzxPMze4bGFy7Lf5mX/2FYn1Foa6r21jhmrj4w8JiM5drHi9yAkV8UTOxN4BIpIGkHeRCEM0RG0I5@aof83SZfEKAKOCUqemtn19QU)

#### Background

This solution makes heavy use of two of Pip's metaoperators:

- `$`, fold. Take a binary operator and apply it between the elements of a list. For instance, `+` is addition, but `$+` sums a list. Note that `$` makes a binary operator into a unary operator.
- `*`, map. Take a unary operator and apply it to each element of a list. For instance, `#` gives the length of a list, but `#*` gives (a list of) the lengths of the list's items.
- These two metaoperators can be combined: `$+*` maps fold/plus over a list, summing each of the list's elements.

The other thing to know about Pip is that a lot of operators work item-wise on lists by default. For instance, `[1 2 3] * 5` gives `[5 10 15]`; `[1 2 3] * [2 3 4]` gives `[2 6 12]`; and `[[1 2] [3 4]] * [5 6]` gives `[[5 10] [18 24]]`.

#### Explanation

We'll use an example input of `[[2 3 4] [2 3 4 6]]`:

- `{...}`
  Defines a function. The (first) argument is bound to the local variable `a`.
- `#*a`
  Map `#` to the function's argument, getting the lengths of the sublists. Result: `[3 4]`
- `a/#*a`
  Divide (the elements of) the sublists of `a` by their respective lengths. Result: `[[0.667 1 1.333] [0.5 0.75 1 1.5]]`
- `$+*a/#*a`
  Map `$+` (fold on addition) to that result, summing the sublists. Result: `[3 3.75]`
- `$CM$+*a/#*a`
  Fold on `CM`, which gives `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on the comparison of its two operands (like Python's `cmp`). Result: `-1` (because `3` is smaller than `3.75`).

---

You can also define functions in Pip by writing expressions containing the identity function `_`. For example, `_*_` is a function that squares its argument--syntactic sugar for `{a*a}`, and fewer bytes. However, there's a bug in the current version of the interpreter that prevents `_` from working with the `*` metaoperator. Once that's fixed, this solution can be **11 bytes**: `$CM$+*_/#*_`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
⟨+/l⟩ᵐ-ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8Fdr6OY/mr3y4dYLuw50L//@PjjbRMY3VAZImsbH/owA)

Outputs `1` if the first list has a bigger average, `-1` is the second list has a bigger average, and `0` if they are tied.

#### Explanation

```
     ᵐ        Map:
⟨   ⟩           Fork:
 +                Sum…
  /               …divided by…
   l              …length
       -      Subtract
        ṡ     Sign
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 105 bytes

```
s->s.stream().map(l->l.stream().reduce((i,j)->i+j).get()/l.size()).reduce((i,j)->Math.signum(i-j)).get();
```

Lambda that takes a nested list, as per allowable inputs.

Streams the list of lists, converts both to their averages, then returns the sign of the difference. `1` if the first list is larger, `-1` if the second list is larger, `0` for a tie.

Comment: Since "anything can be an input", just use `Stream`s directly, [like I did](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130330/16236).

Answer (score 2):

## R <strike>38</strike> 34 bytes

```
function(a,b)sign(mean(a)-mean(b))
```

Function that takes as input two numeric vectors. Returns 1 if first list average is higher, 0 if they are the same and -1 if second list average is higher.

Comment: Is this an anonymous function that can be called without assignment?  I don't know R but if it is you don't need the `f=`.

Comment: @WheatWizard you are correct; additionally you can remove the `{}` from the function body.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's my first attempt at codegolf.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

Don't be so mean!*

```
!-ssZS
```

Input stack order:

```
M
N
```

Output:

```
 1 = N wins  
-1 = M wins  
 0 = tie
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X1G3uDgq@P//aBMdUx0zMDaJ5Yo20jEG0gA)

```
!-ssZS
========
!           % transpose M
 -          % N - M^T using elementwise subtraction and implicit expansion
  s         % sum columns of the result
   s        % sum the resulting row vector
    ZS      % sign of the sum
```

<sub>*This answer was golfed without being mean to any poor, defenseless numbers.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>76</s> 62 bytes

```java
a->b->Math.signum(a.average().orElse(0)-b.average().orElse(0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJRb4IwEMff/RQXE5N2wQacmzA3kyXbkj345N6MD0WLq4OWtMXELHx2dxbcFoUCLf/73b/NcTu@50NdCrXbfB1lUWrjYIcaq5zM2c20d6VllVo7qVVn0DojeHEKlVWayzWsc24tzLlU8N0DaFXruMNpr@UGCoyRhTNSbZcr4GZrqUcB3tqdHt@VW3jj4EO/aLQQ16HZDDJ4OvLhLB3O5tx9Miu3qioIZ3wvDN8KQpk2r7kVJKTDtEulR/DX1G8vlVuuTgOcsM7CU3ssgG8cE6gDnO6hxsU/fRzAXRPC1fgyOgrg1sstcBd0OkSINczEJ4y8hPfoEo7CEIkEX1GTECcBxMjHySWaeHV0xvAr6bBDo7hlIkQmMW4a4hGS6I@tmwJl2pC2SL5ED02h6G@dfn8OcKzeszH8YNsWISd0Ga7o9IpNu9noj10crBMF05VjJfaNy0h/YOEBBizMBqofnNM3QpQfuuktb0IDyBgvy/xAOG0Wz7bpKJLS1r/unZ76@AM)

Since the input can be anything, I decided to take `IntStream`s as input. You can get such an input from a standard `int[]` with `Arrays.stream(array)`.

The output is `1` for "N wins", `-1` for "M wins", and `0` for tie.

#### Saves

- -14 bytes from insights of both @Zircon and @Xanderhall!

Comment: The way you've chosen to take the input is really clever!

Comment: @DavidConrad I actually had the long version of this answer since yesterday (just prepend `java.util.Arrays.stream(array).map(java.util.Arrays::stream)`). It's only when I re-read the question today that I thought this input format is as valid as any.

Comment: Would `.orElse(0)` be a viable shortening of `.getAsDouble()`?

Comment: If you instead just take 2 streams for input, `(a,b)->Math.signum(a.average().orElse(0)-b.average().orElse(0));` is 64 bytes

Comment: These are only good ideas, guys! Continue :p

Comment: I'm not entirely sure `a->b->` counts. If you look at where you're testing it, you have to call 2 different functions to get it to work. It's not a 'single' function or function call.

Comment: @Xanderhall It's called currying, and [it's widely accepted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/is-this-an-acceptable-way-to-shave-a-byte-in-es6).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a 2D array. Returns `-1`  for M, `1` for N or `0` for tie.

```
®x÷ZÊÃrg
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=rnj3WsrDcmc&input=WwpbN10KWzZdCl0)

```
®x÷ZÊÃrg     :Implicit input of 2D array
®            :Map each Z
 x           :  Reduce by addition
  ÷          :  Divide by
   ZÊ        :  Length of Z
     Ã       :End map
      r      :Reduce by
       g     :  Sign of difference
```

Comment: `rn` is a nice trick. Do you need the `g` though?

Comment: @ETHproductions: Yeah, output values need to be consistent.

Comment: If `g` was skippable I could save 6 byes :/

Comment: Oh duh, I'm sorry, I thought `g` got the first item from a 1-item array... :P

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 14 bytes

```
×(-/(+/÷≢)¨∘⊢)
```

`1` if the left is greater, `¯1` if the right is and `0` on tie.

**How?**

`¨∘⊢` for each list

`+/÷≢` calculate average (`+/` sum `÷` divide by `≢` length)

`-/` subtract the averages

`×` sign of the result

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 93 bytes

```
proc C A\ B {proc M L {expr ([join $L +])/[llength $L].}
expr [set n [M $A]-[M $B]]<0?2:$n>0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvLDoIwEEX3fMVdsNAYtR1QWmM0wBa@oHZFiI8QIICJCem318LCEDczc@85MxSVtW3XFEgR35BgnEOODGP5aTus1Kt51vAzbPR6r6qqrO/Dw2W9M95sqL4cUEPl8GO9nVai9Zld6eTXF2Zs@x56qBRjZDAejfZ@RYiDmWa4LAmBK2aIP5sjcCByArmbg5aYM4ZAMnCnCAlBEHLJ5VTQDAny7xVcTIgTIgFiASQ32n4B)

I saved 1 byte returning 2 instead of -1.

Comment: Failed outgolf try: [`proc C args {expr [set n [join [lmap L $args {expr ([join $L +])/[llength $L].}] -]]<0?-1:$n>0}`](https://tio.run/##XYvBCoJAEIbvPcV/8FBEtbNruRtRB6@@gexBRKzYVNQgkH12Ww1i8TLMfN83fW7GsWnrHDGytuwwFJ@mRdoVPSqkz/rhpnllDRIEXrD@qSDBVm8OqTFFVfZ3d@u91dhpfWG3HZ2D6srs2Lz7DmmMIbIYTlav/iDE0U4z9CGHcGCWWNQE4UTkAu52Avc1MQahGMglUkFySOV7NQE@Sw61eAXJSRFHJMGZgCKrxy8)

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

<sup>-1 thanks to @ErikTheOutgolfer</sup>

```
q~{_:+\,d/}%~-g
```

Input is given as `[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]`. Output is -1, 0, or 1.

#### Explanation:

```
q    e# Read input: "[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]"
~    e# Eval:       [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
{    e# For each:     [1 2 3]
 _   e#   Duplicate:  [1 2 3] [1 2 3]
 :+  e#   Sum:        [1 2 3] 6
 \   e#   Swap:       6 [1 2 3]
 ,   e#   Length:     6 3
 d/  e#   Float div:  2.0
}%   e# End:        [2.0 5.0]
~    e# Unpack:     2.0 5.0
-    e# Subtract:   -3.0
g    e# Signum:     -1
```

Comment: You're overusing vectorization, something like `q~{_:+\,d/}%~-g` would be shorter.

Comment: why is sum over 1,2,3 the value 2 and sum over 4,5,6 the value 5?  (might only be typo in explanation)

Comment: @avl42 Golfed and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```
\d+
$*
1(?=.*;(1+,)+)
1$#1$*
1(?<=(,1+)+;.*)
1$#1$*
,

+`1;1
;
D`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpBCsIwFATQ/b@GFdJmKJmf1CZ8ixvBS7iooAs3LsT7xxTBzTDzmPfj83zd6t5d1nq9e@kGoTst42COHr3vhd2OPz0uDvS9t3H4M0T8SqOYnFfWOttBEiZLSKKISK1N2IyINjfR1ggVhoBYAmi5ICtykbKltq0o2wHMalTMGRoiCr8) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder. Takes two comma-separated lists joined with a semicolon and returns `;` for a tie, `1;` if the first list's average is larger and `;1` if the second list's average is. Explanation: The first stage converts to unary. The second stage multiplies each element of the first list by the length of the second list, while the third stage multiplies each element of the second line by the length of the first. The totals on both sides are now the averages multiplied by the product of the length of the lists, so they are directly comparable. The fourth stage totals the values together and the fifth stage subtracts the totals from each other, while the final stage takes the sign of the result.

Comment: The penultimate stage can be `+\`1;1` --> `;` and the final stage can be `D\`1`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Nice; I've never had reason to use the `D` stage before!

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```lisp
(defun g(x)(/(apply'+ x)(length x)))(defun f(x y)(signum(-(g x)(g y))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lczBCsIwEATQe79ibp1Fimhb/0e0WQNpCDaF5uvjCp7EHty97AyPvQW/pFp5n9waodyER15TCqU9wEKYouaHXSIf47ihCBevcZ3ZUd9MrbKpTE8fMx1ofzNOOKPHgEG@ilFg2@zw8T9@@c3rCw)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 40 bytes

```
f x=sum x/sum(1<$x)
x!y=compare(f x)$f y
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 75 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;n=>m=>n.Average()>m.Average?1:m.Average()>n.Average()?2:0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gallina](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html), 103 bytes

```
Definition a l := Z.div (fold_left Z.add l 0) (Zlength l).
Definition g l l' := Z.compare (a l) (a l').
```

Answer (score 1):

## SQL (MS T-SQL), 99 bytes

```
select SIGN((x.a)-(y.a))from(select avg(a) a from(values<list1>)a(a))x,(select avg(a) a from(values<list2>)a(a))y
```

This returns `1` if the first list has a higher average, `0` for ties and `-1` for a heavier second list. Input uses this format: `(1),(2),(3)`, which I have substituted with the placeholders `<list1>` and `<list2>` in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 69 Bytes

```
param($n,$m)(($n|measure -A|% A*)-($m|measure -A|% A*))|% T*g "N;M;T"
```

Outputs `N` when 'N' is bigger, `M` for 'M', and `T` for a Tie.

gets the average using the builtin `Measure-Object -Average` command.

```
PS C:\Users\sweeneyc\Desktop> $t = @((7),(6)
(4,5),(4,4)
(2,3,4),(4,5,6)
(4,1,3),(7,3,2,1,1,2)
(100,390,1),(89,82,89)
(92,892),(892,92)
(10,182),(12,78,203,91))

for ($a=0;$a-lt14;$a+=2){
    .\avg.ps1 -a $t[$a] -b $t[$a+1]
}
A
A
B
T
A
T
T
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 40 + 18 = 58 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;n=>m=>n.Average().CompareTo(m.Average())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZDBasMwDIbveQofY9BC7GRLTJtACWyX7bTBzsFTiyGx19jtGCXPnjlb2WCnGlIdjJD1//okaW@kGXA6WKV35PnTOuyTR6X3qyiSXWstaaJTRHxY1zolydGoN/LUKh3T7/LP5xxn8f1By/U5b0zXoXTKaJs8oMZBSW9u3VppV0OwYH5qsq0mXdV9Vetkc8Sh3WFMvbB/bwd8MXH/V6WT3@IfXuOtTYfJ66Ac@kUx3sYaP8glAKdipJc3342UrhYdn8NtCEAO@eIIHLLZNYgZrnEJBlkIRuG5uRcx4IvDsDSFTKTAQoBKASWHUixOI2ZXHobCQVzjLMDKIBDGoSiBpxkI9oszRuP0BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 20 bytes

```
VRlm&+vlM&+vmc/v/c-s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/LCgnV027LMcXSOQm65fpJ@sW////38TAwABCRINIHVMgEQsA)

Takes input multiplied by 1000. This can be increased to a higher power of 10 for better accuracy.

Takes first input as individual integers, and second input as an array of integers.

Outputs `1` if first array's average is larger

Outputs `-1` if second array's average is larger

Outputs `0` for tie

Only accurate for averages up to 3 decimal places (so if the average of the first list is `3.5554`, and the average of the second list is `3.5557`, this will output `0` for a tie)

### Explanation

```
VRlm&+vlM&+vmc/v/c-s  Implicit input from command-line args
                      2nd input as array is inputted to separate stack
VR                    Create stack3, return to stack1
  lm                  Push length of stack, move it to previous stack (wrap to stack3)
    &+                Sum entire stack
      v               Switch to stack2
       lM             Push length of stack, move it to next stack (stack3)
         &+           Sum entire stack
           v          Switch to stack3
            m         Move last item back to stack2
             c        Collapse stack3 into stack1
              /       Divide
               v      Switch to stack2
                /     Divide
                 c    Collapse into stack1
                  -   Subtract
                   s  Sign, positive becomes 1, negative becomes -1, 0 is not affected.
                      Implicit output of last item on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
±¤-A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYqxDQIxEARzqqCARfKd/dgXUoflHAkhJBAihuBjRA0vfUzyBVwpbsSc@WhnZ/d4v52aLueLzjrV1/Nax3cdPw9dmn512h1aazmWbd6XTQ4YjAKCMcNb9jZg3QjeejTPxgQ2S87BiwPZkgSJkcS09OS/Y8h6BKVuiBET2HkIlR8) Outputs -1 if **N** wins, 1 if **M** wins, and 0 if they are tied. Just takes the sign (`±`) of the difference  (`-`) between the averages (`¤..A`) of the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

Takes two lists `n` and `m`. Returns `True` if the average of `n` is larger, `False` if that of `m` is, and throws a `ZeroDivisionError` if they are equal.

```python
lambda n,m:1/(sum(n)/len(n)-sum(m)/len(m))>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9fKUF@juDRXI09TPyc1D0jpgni5EF6upqadwf@Cosy8Eo00jWjzWB2FaLNYTU0uuJCJjoIpSBRIm6BIGOkoGIPEIHKm6NJAMUOgCpC0OVilEVgAiIyA6v4DAA)

Comment: Does not work for ties. Erros may not be thrown as a form of output

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Am I interpreting [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) incorrectly? Specifically "Programs may output to STDERR" and "Functions may output via the same methods as full programs".

Comment: Your forms of output must be constant. You cannot use both STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Got it, I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <strike>87</strike> <strike>101</strike> 84 Bytes

```
def c(M,N):
  j=sum(N)/len(N)-sum(M)/len(M);print('N')if j>0else print('MT'[j==0])
```

input is standard Python lists called `M` and `N`
Output is name of larger list or `T` for tie.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcrBDoIwDIDhO0/R27akRtiGJJr5BtvJ27ITjghBJIIHn352YmIvzfe383u9PSaV0jV20HKLThwLoBnM8rpzJ/ZjnGjtsuwmK07zs59WzhwTfQfDuYzjEuEX7YX5wZgyiNRy3wQEfwggCoLGOlOjDrAViYrwbTX@3ypUOTZ0lYQKJZ3SBw)

### Explanation

Get an int to represent the comparison.

Compare in nested ternary.

Thank you @Morgan Thrapp for the improvements!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! 

Where are you taking the input? Right now it looks like you're assuming that the lists are hard coded. This is generally not allowed, see [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/38770) for more details.

Also, you can save a few bytes by removing the whitespace after numbers/parenthesis and using the implicit conversion between boolean and int to index a string in your print call, instead of writing out full print calls/ternaries. Eg, `print('N') if j>0 else print('TM'[j==0])`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 + 1 (`-a`) = 45bytes

```perl
push@a,eval(join'+',@F)/@F}{say$a[1]<=>$a[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gtDjDIVEntSwxRyMrPzNPXVtdx8FNU9/Brba6OLFSJTHaMNbG1g5IG8T@/2@kYKpgwWUCJM3@5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0@K@bCAA)

Outputs `-1` if the first has a greater average, `1` if the second has the greater average, or `0` if the averages are equal.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 69 bytes

```
{for(i=0;i++<NF;)d=M[NR-1]-(M[NR]+=$i/NF)}z=(NR-1)%2{$0=(d<0)-(d>0)}z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo9C8IwEIb3/Ip3qJBQineXahPaOHazg6t0EEqhOAgugsXfHi/D@/XcPT7PnPf19bZbon6r62Eae7ek6326NTw3tpS5TtV2nEb3@yZbuDvIXlGyy0CuscuF9JJzZ86mxUnVGoFX14XCGN50SkQbQwwTwUcCmxARBCGaWFx0C2J5AAcNQRcg5BH5Dw)

Input is by rows with odd row line numbers corresponding to `N` and even rows corresponding to `M`. Output is -1 if `N` is greater than `M`. 0 if they are equal, and 1 if `M` > `N`. Output only occurs on even rows.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 24 bytes

Returns `1` if the first list has the greater average, `-1` if the second list, or `0` for a tie.

```ruby
:*&:/%[:sum|Q,:+@]|+:<=>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWO6y01Kz0VaOtiktzawJ1rLQdYmu0rWxs7SDS2woU3KKjo410jHVMYnWiTXRMdcxiY2MhkgsWQGgA)

### Explanation

```
:* & :/ % [:sum | Q, :+@] | +:<=>

:* &                               # Map arguments with...
     :/ % [        ,    ]          #   Quotient of...
           :sum | Q                #     Sum of list converted to float and
                     :+@           #     Length of list
                          | +:<=>  # Then compare
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$=>[compare average&average&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?YZh5AO)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 bytes

```
€mẸṛ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqx41rcl9uGvHw52zlxQnJRdDhRdsjzY0MNAxtjTQMYzVUYi2sNSxMNKxsIyFSAMA)

Gives `1` for N wins, `0` for tie, and `-1` for M wins.

##### Explanation

```python
€mẸṛ  # Implicit input
€m    # Mean of each
  Ẹṛ  # Compare them
      # Implicit output
```